# Django - Getting contact permission from users

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

On my sign up forms, I am asking users if I can contact them via email or SMS.

I am using Django-Allauth and it doesn't seem to list it as an option. I am subclassing the view and trying to sneak it in there:

```
class ListenSignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'listen_signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.allows_contact = self.request.POST.get('allows_contact')
        return super(ListenSignupView, self).form_valid(form)
```

However, it doesn't actually save the result to the user. Do I also need to subclass the forms? What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, overriding the forms is pretty simple:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm


class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(CustomSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user_input = request.POST.get('allows_contact')
        user.allows_contact = True if user_input == "on" else False
        user.save()
        return user
```

This can be done for any of allauth's forms. [Here are the relevant docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#account-forms), for reference.